# Единый стиль с разным цветом

Tags: css

[есть кнопка переключатель](https://www.tutorialstonight.com/css-toggle-switch-with-text?utm_content=cmp-true), и необходимо ее использовать многоразово, но цвет необходимо менять

нашла [в документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties), что можно использовать `var` и инитиализировать ее в `root`, что я и сделала, а как можно, при различных условиях менять значение `var`

```
:root {
  --filter-color: lightgreen;
  /*lightblue | lightgreen*/
}
```

без джаваскрипта, проект на СиШарпе Блазор

как вы используте одинаковый стиль с разным цветом, чтоб не повторять код стиля несколько раз.

```css
:root {
  --filter-color: lightgreen;
  /*lightblue | lightgreen*/
}

.toggle {
  --width: 80px;
  --height: calc(var(--width) / 3);
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  /*box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);*/
  border-radius: var(--height);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle input {
  display: none;
}

.toggle .slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: var(--height);
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle .slider::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(var(--height));
  height: calc(var(--height));
  border-radius: calc(var(--height) / 2);
  background-color: #fff;
  /*box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);*/
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: var(--filter-color);
}

.toggle input:checked+.slider::before {
  transform: translateX(calc(var(--width) - var(--height)));
}

.toggle .labels {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle .labels::after {
  content: attr(data-off);
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  color: #4d4d4d;
  opacity: 1;
  /*text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);*/
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle .labels::before {
  content: attr(data-on);
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0;
  /*text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);*/
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle input:checked~.labels::after {
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggle input:checked~.labels::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<label class="toggle">
       <input type="checkbox">
       <span class="slider"></span>
       <span class="labels" data-on="ON" data-off="OFF"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Код всего стиля не нужно повторять весь. Достаточно указать только то, что будет меняться... ;) ЦСС, как правило, статичен. Но он может содержать разные комбинации.

Comment: @ksa спасибо за отзыв, я указала, что необходимо менять, а как `.toggle input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: var(--filter-color);}` можно менять в различных кнопках

Comment: вернее менять сам `background-color`, то есть весь стиль тот же, но цвет `.toggle input:checked+.slider` менять при применении данного стиля

Comment: Я не понял этого вопроса...

Comment: @ksa есть две кнопки, ВЕСЬ `css` что в вопросе к ним применяется, НО `background-color` для `.toggle input:checked+.slider` у них разный

Comment: ... *Достаточно указать только то, что будет меняться... ;)*  где и как)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@ksa** *Достаточно указать только то, что будет меняться... ;)*

ну я думала, думала, думала над Вашим комментарием и просто вместо класса использовала `id` для двух кнопок

```css
.toggle {
  --width: 128px;
  --height: calc(var(--width) / 4);
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  /*box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);*/
  border-radius: var(--height);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle input {
  display: none;
}

.toggle .slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: var(--height);
  background-color: #dee0e3;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle .slider::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(var(--height));
  height: calc(var(--height));
  border-radius: calc(var(--height) / 2);
  background-color: black;
  /*box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);*/
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

#btnBlue input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#btnGreen input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.toggle input:checked+.slider::before {
  transform: translateX(calc(var(--width) - var(--height)));
}

.toggle .labels {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle .labels::after {
  content: attr(data-off);
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  color: black;
  opacity: 1;
  /*text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);*/
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle .labels::before {
  content: attr(data-on);
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  color: black;
  opacity: 0;
  /*text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);*/
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle input:checked~.labels::after {
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggle input:checked~.labels::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<label class="toggle" id="btnBlue">
       <input type="checkbox" checked="@isChecked" @oninput="someAction1">
       <span class="slider"></span>
       <span class="labels" data-on="BlueOn" data-off="BlueOff"></span>
</label>
<label class="toggle" id="btnGreen">
       <input type="checkbox" checked="@isChecked" @oninput="someAction2" >
       <span class="slider"></span>
       <span class="labels" data-on="GreenOn" data-off="GreenOff"></span>
</label>
```